# Click on "New to Dropbox? Get the App!", it does not show or redirect on the dropbox site

Tags: ios, swift, swiftydropbox

I am using outh controller to access the dropbox but when in the bottom I click on "New to Dropbox? Get the App!", it does not show or redirect on the dropbox site.

Check the attached screen shot:

[image]